# Qual é a forma certa de abreviar "velocidade"?

Tags: abreviações

Qual é a forma certa de abreviar "velocidade"? "vel." ou "veloc."?

Comment: Depende do contexto, em física é: v.

Comment: Na física não é uma abreviação, é um símbolo matemático.

Answer (score 1):

A [ABL](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/reducoes) aponta para duas:

> V.
>
> vel.

Importante notar que não é “v.” nem “Vel.”, mas sim “V.” e “vel.”.

Comment: nas formúlas em física se usa: v.  Uma *ve* minúscula.

Comment: @Lambie, como "v = d/t" dizes?

Comment: No contexto da física é usual usar "v" como símbolo para a velocidade, mas é comum usar outras letras, como "w" — e, novamente, é um símbolo (matemático), não uma abreviação.

Answer (score 0):

A forma correta de abreviação de velocidade é Vel.

Comment: bem-vindo ao Portuguese StackExchange! Neste site, tenta-se trabalhar com referência, preferencialmente de alta qualidade, para que as palavras tenham força. Entenda: a força da tua resposta, estando certa ou errada, é a mesma desta “para abreviar ‘velocidade’, usa-se ‘vúl.’”. Mas obrigado pela contribuição, de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 0):

Vel. é a abreviatura correta de velocidade. Muitas abreviaturas são utilizadas na sinalização do trânsito para passar mensagens curtas e eficazes ao mesmo tempo.